# I get 'The page you requested is invalid' when I enter the info from 'Account Recovery'

Tags: support, openid

I've had a stackoverflow.com id that worked well with Mac/Safari browser, and I used google(gmail) provide OpenID. The problem was that, I can't use the OpenID when I login with other browsers.

I used the 'Can't remeber your login information?' to get something like 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=BlahBlah', which ends up having 'The page you requested is invalid.' message from Google accounts.

In the course of the attempt to get out of this situation, I happened to make another User ID with different OpenID with the same gmail address for the first User ID, and I can't assign the gmail address to this new User ID, as it's already taken.

Even worse, after my log out, I can't login again with the first User ID, And I can't use the second User ID, as I can't assign my gmail address to it.

- Q : Is there any way to login with my 'first User ID' without using open ID?
- Q : Is there any way to reset my open ID?
- Q : Can I delete the wrong user id so that I can login with 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id' at my PC?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are using the same google account, you should just be able to click the "Google" button or enter the openid address `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id` (and then use the same google account).

Google openid is specific both the the google user account and the originating url, so you *won't* get the same id between (for example) stackoverflow and serverfault, but you should get the same id whenever you go to stackoverflow.

We can merge accounts etc. Can you point me at them so I can sanity check this?

Comment: After some google search, I knew that there has been a lot of complaints about the google openid. I don't know what was the problem exactly, but this is the solution that I know.

1. Make another google id with 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'. The email request might popup.
2. Send an email to 'team@stackoverflow.com' to request a merge.
3. Make 'myopenid.com' for another openid.

@Marc : The id is merged, and thanks for the work.